# Interpret double written as hex

Tags: hex, double

I am working with doubles (64-bit) stored in a file by printing the raw bytes from the C# representation. For example the decimal number 0.95238095238095233 is stored as the bytes "9e e7 79 9e e7 79 ee 3f" in hex. Everything works as expected, I can write and read, but I would like to be able to understand this representation of the double myself.

According to the C# documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7.2#explicit-interface-implementations and wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format the first bit is supposedly the sign with 0 for positive and 1 for negative numbers. However, no matter the direction I read my bytes, the first bit is 1. Either 9 = 1001 or f = 1111. I am puzzled since 0.95... is positive.

As a double check, the following python code returns the correct decimal number as well.
`unpack('d', binascii.unhexlify("9ee7799ee779ee3f"))`

Can anyone explain how a human can read these bytes and get to 0.95238095238095233?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct value? Because your binary representation does not match the [number](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QuF7cf),

Comment: You might want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: You made a mistake when reading the string. The a hex byte takes _two_ numers, so in fact your fist byte is `0x9e` (10010100 on little endian). This does not show effects here, but see my previous comment.

Comment: I should have been more clear about what I do, please see code snippet [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7FQh1)

Comment: Figured it out, the collection of bytes are read like a 64-bit number(right to left), but each byte is read like a string(left to right). So my bytes should be read "3F" first, 3F reads left to right, so I'm starting with the bits 0011 1111 etc. This gives the IEEE 754 encoding as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the collection of bytes are read like a 64-bit number (first bit on the left), but each byte is read like a string(first bit on the right). So my bytes should be read "3F" first, 3F reads left to right, so I'm starting with the bits 0011 1111 etc. This gives the IEEE 754 encoding as expected: First bit is the sign, next 11 bits the exponent, and then the fraction.